# Using history.js with dynamic (ajax) modal boxes

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, pushstate, history.js

I have a modal box (Twitter Bootstrap) that I'm trying to control during various actions:

1. User clicks link > shows modal box, changes (pushstate) URL.
2. User hides modal box > Changes URL to previous page.
3. User clicks back button > hides modal box, URL changes to previous page.
4. User clicks forward button > shows modal box, changes (pushstate) URL.

My main issue is with items #3 and #4.  The modal needs to toggle when the back/forward browser buttons are used (The URL changes)

Here is my current code that works only actions #1 and #2:

```
$(function(){
$(".thumbnail a").live("click", function(){
    msgurl = $(this).attr("href");
    msgid = $(this).attr("data-id");
    history.pushState(null, null, msgurl);

    $.ajax({
        ....
    });
    $("#newmodal").modal({ dynamic: true });
     return false;
});
$('#newmodal').bind('hidden', function () {
    history.back();
})
});
```

Is there a way to achieve back/forward button control using a history library, such as history.js?  How would I implement it into my code?

Answer (score 6):

I've actually been trying to do something very similar…

So far I've had success with all your points (1-4), but I'm still working on a way for HTML4 browsers to display a cleaner link (using history.js produces an ugly http://domain.org/page/page#-http://domain.org/modalpage that isn't linkable).

Here's some tips to get yours working:

Be sure to bind to the onpopstate event.  This way you can capture a the browser's forward and back buttons and figure out what to do:

```
window.onpopstate = function(e) {
var State = e.state;
if (!State) { //i.e., we've gone to the history context (no active state)
    $('#modal').modal('hide');
}
else {//Re-open state modal
    var modalURL = State.URL.substring(State.URL.indexOf('?show=')+6);
    openModal(appRoot+modalURL, State);
}
}
```

The onpopstate function isn't perfect since you can't access the previous state object (or at least I cannot find a way to) so you may want to append a variable to your URLs.  In my example, my URLs have '?show=relativeModalLink/' appended so I know what page the modal was opened on.  This way you can also use server side code to detect if the show URL variable is passed, and either direct the user to the modal page or bring them back to the main page and open a modal (a matter of preference).

And the reason you check if the state is null is because when you load a page, the browser will actually have a state, it's just null.  So null can be seen as the absence of a modal.

When you open the modal, do something like this:

```
function openModal(modalLink, state) {    
if (state === undefined) {
       var shortLink = modalLink.substring(modalLink.indexOf(appRoot)+appRoot.length);
       var stateLink = document.location.href.indexOf('?show=') === -1 ? document.location.href+'?show='+shortLink : document.location.href;
       history.pushState({'type': 'modal','URL':stateLink},'',stateLink);
    }
}
```

Notice that I passed the state to my open modal function, since we don't want to push another state in the case that the user has used the forward button and moved to a pre-existing modal state.

This is a bit specific to my implementation, so your link system may be a bit different.

Also one more gotcha: be sure to bind the window.history.back() function directly to bootstrap's close button (DO NOT put it inside bootstrap's 'hidden' modal function).  This way, the user pressing back won't move the page back twice in my code (since in the onpopstate function I call .modal('hide')).  I haven't yet found a way to detect if the back button was pressed or if the modal was closed with the close button from within bootstrap's 'hidden' function (in fact, I don't think it's possible…).

To implement history.js, just include the script on your page.  It will be ignored in HTML5 browsers, and it seems to work okay with the above code in HTML4 browsers (minus the ugly URL issue mentioned earlier).  The implementation instructions in the history.js docs are different, but 'ajaxifying' a page is a bit different than a modal situation.

Hope this helps!